# use durandal.js for single page application in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am developing single page application in sharepoint 2013. I have some doubts about implementation

1. I should have something which can be use to maintain history and use for navigation ( as it is single page application)
2. It should bind the data (can do with knockout.js)
3. It should give me backend some notification (eg. Data has been saved etc this thing also can be done by knockout.js)

But when I searched about this I get to know that we can do all this things with Durandal.js http://durandaljs.com/

Please tell me it is feasible to use such frameworks in the sharepoint or not? 
Is anybody implemented such kind of scinarioes?

Comment: We have been able to implement a big data-driven one-page application using knockout.js in SharePoint 2013 (as a webpart) and it worked great. Never used durandal, though I can't imagine why it wouldn't work with sharepoint?

Comment: thanks for comment but I expect some more explaination about this

Comment: because I have seen some documents where durandal.js is used with sharepoint 2013
http://sympmarc.com/2013/04/15/spservices-stories-13-durandal-sp3-developing-sharepoint-spas-made-easy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article [Durandal meets SharePoint 2013](http://rainerat.spirit.de/2013/02/21/durandal-meets-sharepoint-2013/), one can read:

> Let me introduce you to Durandal, a pretty young SPA framework, which is named after a famous French sword. As it states on the web site
>
> *Your search for a SPA framework ends here.*
>
> Durandal claims to be comfortable
>
> *We didn’t try to re-invent the wheel. Durandal is built on libs you know and love like jQuery, Knockout and RequireJS. There’s little to learn and building apps feels comfortable and familiar. Dive in and enjoy.*
>
> Durandal claims to run Anyone and Everyone
>
> *In the end, Durandal is just a collection of JavaScript libraries, so you don’t need anything special to use it. Hop on over to our github repo and fork away. You can just grab the contents of the App folder and use it to kickstart your own project.*

Where they actually test if it is possible, and come to this conclusion:

> I’d say that Durandal can fulfill the promise of Your search for a SPA framework ends here.

## Conclusion

Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @PrasadGavande You're welcome!

Comment: Do u have any idea how should I proceed for this. because I could not find anything to start with sharepoint 2013.If you have some links regarts to this please share with me

Comment: @PrasadGavande Add the link to durandal.js and your custom js file in the master page and work your way from there. Good Luck!

Comment: little problem with durandalJS. ie. I can route HTML files with js in simple asp.net web application but I want to route aspx file 
so that while implementing in sharpoint I can use aspx file as module and then call that file 
it there anyway to do (call aspx file from router of durandal)

Comment: @PrasadGavande I'm sorry, that's outside of my knowledge base. Maybe ask on our sister site Stackoverflow?